# Creating a @ManyToOne object using json

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to achieve Many to one relationship where stations are belong to regions. How can I achieve this using REST to create station by just passing the region ID in the POST station json as shown.

```
{
    "name": "New York",
    "code": "MGR",
    "active": "YES",
    "regionid": 1

}
```

Below is my controller.

```
@PostMapping("/station/create/")
public ResponseObject create(@Valid @RequestBody Station station){
    ResponseObject responseObject = new ResponseObject();
    responseObject.setSuccess(true);
    responseObject.setData(stationDao.save(station));
    responseObject.setMessage("Station created successfully");
    return responseObject;
}
```

Below are my models.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "regions")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Region implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonProperty("regionID")
    private Long regionID;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("active")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private YesNo active;
}





@Entity
@Table(name = "stations")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Station implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonProperty("stationID")
    private Long stationID;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonProperty("regionID")
    @JoinColumn(name = "regionid", referencedColumnName = "regionid")
    private Region region;

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("code")
    private String code;
    @JsonProperty("active")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private YesNo active;
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: 16,770 WARN  [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter] (default task-1) Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.apas.region.model.Station]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': no back reference property found from type [simple type, class com.apas.region.model.Region]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@JoinColumn(name = "regionid", referencedColumnName = "regionid")
    private Region region;
```

`referencedColumnName` not exist in Regioin class. It will be `regionID` instead of `regionid`.

Try with below change:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "regionid", referencedColumnName = "regionID")
        private Region region;
```

Comment: Will this allow me to create a station with the following json?

Comment: {
    "name": "New York",
    "code": "MGR",
    "active": "YES",
    "regionid": 1

} It is still throwing the same error

Comment: you pass "regionid" : "1" . Region is object in Station class. you can pass like it: { "name": "New York", "code": "MGR", "active": "YES", "regionID" : { "regionID" : "1"}}

Comment: Is there a way i can get the regionID in the request body if sent as { "name": "New York", "code": "MGR", "active": "YES", "regionid": 1   without creating the object "regionID" : { "regionID" : "1"}

Comment: you can do it using JsonCreator or JsonSetter

Answer (score 0):

I realized I do not need @JsonManagedReference
Thus my code will be

```
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonProperty("regionID")
    @JoinColumn(name = "regionid", referencedColumnName = "regionID")
    private Region region;
```

And boommmm.......